# installed ubuntu alongside windows, locked out of windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I had windows 10 installed on my computer and wanted to install Ubuntu 19.10 alongside it. Everything worked but on boot it went straight to Windows instead of the GRUB menu and I didn't want to have to go into bios settings every time I wanted to start Ubuntu. So I found some article (https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/) that made me use this command in windows: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and I used it without much thinking about it. Now I can't get into windows anymore no mather what device I boot from it always just goes straight to ubuntu

Comment: You should not mess with the Win10 boot manager file unless you know what you're doing. Normally you cannot fix it from Ubuntu. But if you go to `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot` you'll see a file BCD and maybe one named BCD.Backup.0001. If so, rename BCD -> BCD.bad, and the backup -> BCD. You'll need root permission for this. Then reboot and you may get lucky. Otherwise you'll have to to rebuild BCD using either of [these tools](https://www.ubackup.com/articles/create-a-system-repair-disc-4348.html).

Comment: you can try boot-repair. Might work see this
https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This video helped me:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_I4K2-Rr_Y

Use a windows bootable dvd, open the command line, use diskpart to assign a letter to your EFI partition, format it, use bcdboot to create a new EFI directory